# Linking an IMG inserted from CSS to another page when clicked?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Just wanting to know if it's possible to insert a link to a html page when you click the image I have inserted via CSS.

```
width : 50%;
height : 40px;
float : left;
background-image:url(Buttons/BTN_NAME.png);
background-repeat: no repeat; 
background-size : 100% 100%;
```

For example, When i click the "BTN_NAME" image when it's displayed in the Div I have inserted it into, how to i link that to say a "Home" page via CSS?
All help much appreciated.

Comment: couldnt you just have a click event on the div that the image is in?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not very clear but as far as I understood you want to make a div clickable which is linked to a page. If so, there are many ways to do that but the way you want it would be something like this.
You put the css rules in a class like

```
.link
{
    width : 50%;
    height : 40px;
    float : left;
    background-image:url(Buttons/BTN_NAME.png);
    background-repeat: no repeat; 
    background-size : 100% 100%;
}
```

and the you anchor tag with the above class name

```
<a class="link" href="page.html">Link text</a>
```

If you don't want the text to be visible then just add the following property in .link css class

```
text-indent:-9999px;
```

now the image will be linked to "page.html".

If you can provide more detailed requirement with code may be someone can help you with a better solution.

Comment: Thanks a million. I have added an onClick function to the div in question, It works fine for Chrome, But when i try to view it on my android it doesn't work. I will give your solution a shot tomorrow! Thanks again.